# Error in Capturing Frames in JavaCV

Tags: javacv

All:

I am running Windows XP (32 Bit) with 32 Bit Java and 32 Bit OpenCV 2.4.3. When I attempt to capture a video frame from an AVI with following code in Eclipse:

```
import com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber.Exception;
import com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber;

public class FrameReader
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception,
            InterruptedException
    {


         OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber("hall_gray.avi");        
         grabber.start();
         grabber .release();
        return;
    }//End method
}//End class
```

The following error happens:

========================== Start of Error =========================

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x77c46fa3, pid=4776, tid=3392

JRE version: 7.0_02-b13
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (22.0-b10 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
 Problematic frame:
 C  [msvcrt.dll+0x36fa3]

Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

An error report file with more information is saved as:
 C:\Java Projects\JavaCVTester\hs_err_pid4776.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

==================== End of Error Message ==================

Could someone help me out on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try with [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) and `FFmpegFrameGrabber` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall your jre.
Also goto the windows startup & recovery option. Choose "writing debugging option" to "Complete memory dump".

Answer (score 0):

The `OpenCVFrameGrabber` does not support many video formats. The error message "[...]  Problematic frame: C [msvcrt.dll+0x36fa3] [...]" probably points out, that your video format may not be supported.

The `FFmpegFrameGrabber` is more flexible. Try the following code:

```java
import com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber.Exception;

public class FrameReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {    
        FrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("hall_gray.avi");
        grabber.start();
        grabber.release();
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaCV, you can use FFmpegFrameGrabber which is a wrapper of OpenCVFrameGrabber and it has a lot of methods rather than OpenCVFrameGrabber.

Try the following code to extract and save the frames from the video:

```
import java.io.File;
import com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.Frame;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvSaveImage;
public class Getting_Frames
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
 {
    File f = new File("example.avi");
    FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(f);

   try {
            grabber.start();
        } catch (com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber.Exception e1) {
        }
   long frameLength = grabber.getLengthInFrames();
        int increment = (int) Math.ceil(frameLength / 30);
        if (frameLength < 30) {
            System.err.println("Not enough frames");
        }

     // To grab frames per 30 seconds    
        Frame[] s_frame = new Frame[1000];
           for (int i=0, frame_counter = 0; i < frameLength; frame_counter++) {
            if((frame_counter % 2000 )==0)
            {
                s_frame[i]=grabber.grabKeyFrame();
                 IplImage temp = s_frame[i].image;
                System.out.println(temp.nChannels()+" "+temp.origin()+" "+temp.highValue());
                cvSaveImage(i+"new.jpg",temp);
                i++;
            }
        }
      // To know number for each video
      System.out.println(frameLength);

  }
}
```